# How do I implement a raw frame capture using Python 3.3?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

*Note: I'm not sure if this is a programming issue, or a hardware/OS specific related issue.*

I'm trying to capture raw ethernet frames using Python 3.3's socket class.  Looking directly at the example from the [PyDoc's website](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html):

```
import socket
import struct


# CAN frame packing/unpacking (see 'struct can_frame' in <linux/can.h>)

can_frame_fmt = "=IB3x8s"
can_frame_size = struct.calcsize(can_frame_fmt)

def build_can_frame(can_id, data):
    can_dlc = len(data)
    data = data.ljust(8, b'\x00')
    return struct.pack(can_frame_fmt, can_id, can_dlc, data)

def dissect_can_frame(frame):
    can_id, can_dlc, data = struct.unpack(can_frame_fmt, frame)
    return (can_id, can_dlc, data[:can_dlc])


# create a raw socket and bind it to the 'vcan0' interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.CAN_RAW)
s.bind(('vcan0',))

while True:
    cf, addr = s.recvfrom(can_frame_size)

    print('Received: can_id=%x, can_dlc=%x, data=%s' % dissect_can_frame(cf))

    try:
        s.send(cf)
    except OSError:
        print('Error sending CAN frame')

    try:
        s.send(build_can_frame(0x01, b'\x01\x02\x03'))
    except OSError:
        print('Error sending CAN frame')
```

I get the following error:

> OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol.

breaking at this specific line:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.CAN_RAW)
```

The only changes I've made to the code was the actual interface name (i.e. 'em1').  I'm using Fedora 15.

Looking further into the Python Source code it *appears* that the AF_CAN (address family) and the CAN_RAW (protocol) aren't the correct pair.

How do I capture raw ethernet frames for further processing?

---

Ultimately what I need to be able to do is capture raw ethernet frames and process them as this come into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to do this with the following:

```
import socket
import struct
import time


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))

test = []

while(1):
    now = time.time()
    message = s.recv(4096)
    # Process the message from here
```

Comment: I am using same line in my program: s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003)) and getting error that .. _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted .. what should I use instead of these parameters?

Comment: You running on Linux?  If so you'll need to run as a super user.

Comment: I am using Linux, but  how I can do that if I am using Django framework?